# Shadow Map with directional light - shadow too small

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

I am having trouble implementing a simple **shadow mapping** algorithm for a directional light. The shadow that is cast from my cube object on ground plane is too small and i can't figure out why! Please help guys!

Here is an image of the scene  as seen from light's "position" [A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYFmI.png), and here my cube's shadow [B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdiac.png). Shadow on image B is acting as if only the cube's top front face is casting shadow, completely ignoring cube's top face!

Here are my projection matrices and light position:

```
glm::vec3 worldSpace_lightPos  = glm::vec3( 0.0f, 4.0f, -1.0f );

glm::vec3 worldSpace_planePos  = glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
glm::vec3 worldSpace_cubePos   = glm::vec3( 0.0f, 1.5f, 1.0);

glm::vec3 lightSpace_cameraDir = worldSpace_cubePos + glm::vec3(0.5f);

glm::mat4 V = glm::lookAt( glm::vec3(-8.0f, 7.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0,0,0), glm::vec3(0,1,0) );
glm::mat4 P = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f/3.0f, 0.01f, 100.0f);

glm::mat4 depthV = glm::lookAt(worldSpace_lightPos, worldSpace_cubePos + glm::vec3(0.5f), glm::vec3(0,1,0));
glm::mat4 depthP = glm::ortho<float>(-10,10,-20,20,1,9.5);
```

Here are my texture params:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, color);
```

My 2nd pass fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 eyeSpace_coordinates;
in vec3 eyeSpace_normals;
in vec4 lightSpace_coordinates;

uniform sampler2D ShadowMap;

uniform vec3 lightDir;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;


float calculateShadow()
{
    float bias = 0.0005f;
    float isShadowed = 1.0f;

    vec3 nuevo = lightSpace_coordinates.xyz;

float closestDepth = texture(ShadowMap, nuevo.xy).r;
float currentDepth = nuevo.z - bias;

if( currentDepth > closestDepth )
    isShadowed = 0.3f;

return isShadowed;
}

void main()
{ 
float shadow = calculateShadow();

gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3(shadow), 1.0f ) * vec4( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Common way to debug shadow map issues is to render the depth map. Make sure that `lightSpace_coordinates` has a correct value.

Comment: Thanks dude! I rendered it to the depth map and realized what my problem is exactly, though i don't know how to fix it.. Turns out that when i render my shadow map, during the first pass, the light's camera doesn't use the position or the direction i'm expecting it to use. So it could be that i'm passing in incorrect lightSpace_coordinates, as you said. Or maybe the problem is something else. I'll post my discoveries here in a few hours

Comment: Ok, turns out everything is running as it should, i just didn't understand how directional lights and orthographic work..